# Changing JSON Provider (Spring / Spring-Boot)

Tags: json, spring, spring-boot, jackson, jettison

Is it possible to use **Jettison** with Spring / Spring-Boot instead of default JSON Provider **Jackson**? I have one such requirement to match Json output with an very old project which used Jettison.

If yes, can i get some pointers/hints please?

Comment: What's producing the output? Is it a Spring MVC controller or something else?

Comment: yes. A `@RestController` with `@RequestMapping`

Comment: Look at http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-spring-mvc-message-converters

Comment: @nurgasemetey : wow! that's great!! Do i need to define custom JAXB too if i choose custom JSON?

Comment: It seems so. However as `orschach` said, it can be cumbersome thing which is not advisable, you can tweak `jackson`. Look at `jackson` configuration options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible but you're going to be doing a lot of hacking and writing boiler-plate configuration code as Jackson is embedded pretty deep inside Spring.

It might be easier for you to leverage Jackson's functionality to serialize/deserialize your data in the format you need (instead of the format Jackson silently provides)?

Comment: Tried the jackson way, but there are some issues with elements with properties. They both represent them differently. And also everything shows as strings in jettison, while in jackson, types are different.